# Intercepting anchor href on an SVG

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, mouseevent, href

In [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-href-link-mouseevent-9nplt?file=/src/SVGSample.html) I have a react app example with an iFrame that loads an HTML file and adds a click event listener to it.

The reason is to detect `href`s on click and act accordingly. The HTML also includes an SVG part that I have a problem getting the `href` with the hostname.

```
    <div>
      <a href="/items/1234"> Link outside of SVG</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 756 1315">
        <a href="/items/1234" id="huvud">
          <path
            d="M342...14.07Z"
            id="myID"
            fill="#5fe4"
            opacity="50"
          ></path>
        </a>
      </svg>
    </div>
```

getting the `href` with the following snippet from `MouseEvent`

```
let target = event.target! as HTMLAnchorElement;
    const link = isHyperlink(target) ? target : closestATag(target);
    if (!link) return;
    const theHREF = link.href;
```

For the fist `<a>` tag the `href` is with correct and with hostname (i.g http://localhost:3000/items/1234)

For the `<a>` tag inside SVG the link.href returns `SVGAnimatedString:{baseVal:string, animVal:string}` and getting href with `link.getAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href')` does not contain hostname.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Frederic Brüning, my scenario was specific to handle all anchor links.

> the [xlink:href is depricated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href)

So the a tags in SVG does not need `xlink:href="xxx"` but only `href="xxx"`

then the `getAttributeNS` does not need namespace. `getAttributeNS('','href')` which returns `href` (exact string value) for any `<a>` tag

Then appending origin will fix my problem

```js
theUrl = `${window.location.origin}${link.getAttributeNS('','href')}`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the uri adding xlink: before the href attributes in your anchor tags. Maybe then add the current location like this:

```
window.location.hostname + link.getAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "href");


<a xlink:href="/items/1234" id="huvud">
      <path
        d="M342...14.07Z"
        id="myID"
        fill="#5fe4"
        opacity="50"
      ></path>
</a>
```

You can also get the baseURI from the node element of the attribute.

```
let node = link.getAttributeNodeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "href")

node.baseURI + node.value
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. FYI `getAttributeNodeNS ` does not work on Safari